# How to input 1~2 instead of 1 2. InputMismatchException

Tags: java, fibonacci, inputmismatchexception

So I was solving a problem on Techgig which goes like this :
There I have to print the sequence of Fibonacci numbers till 10 places in array and the first two inputs were entered by the user.

My code goes like:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class CandidateCode{

    public static void main(String args1[]) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int first=sc.nextInt();
        int second=sc.nextInt();
        int [] array=new int[10];
        array[0]=first;
        array[1]=second;
        int i;
        for(i=2;i<10;i++)
        {
            array[i]=first+second;
            first=array[i-1];
            second=array[i];
        }
        System.out.print("{"+array[0]);
        for(i=1;i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(","+array[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("}");
    }
}
```

Now the sample input should go like 1 2 and output should be displayed as {1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89}

But they have used Test Case as 1~2 and the code when compiled gives InputMismatchException. Please provide me a method to remove this Exception

Comment: You can read input as a string and then split it using '~' as the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will resolve your problem.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CandidateCode{

public static void main(String args1[]) throws Exception
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=sc.next();
    int first=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,s.indexOf("~")));
    int second=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.indexOf("~")+1));
    int [] array=new int[10];
    array[0]=first;
    array[1]=second;
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<10;i++)
    {
        array[i]=first+second;
        first=array[i-1];
        second=array[i];
    }
    System.out.print("{"+array[0]);
    for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(","+array[i]);
    }
    System.out.print("}");
}
}
```

Read a input string of format "Num1~Num2" and then extract the numbers from this string.

Comment: Thanks Dude . But 1 of the 3 test cases still fail.